# Android Studio unable to read Mega .so library

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to integrate Mega Api in Android. They have lib.so which i need to add in Android Studio.

Here is my code

[image]

However it fails to load the libs

Here is what i get

```
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.neberox.app.libraries.mega.megaJNI.swig_module_init:()V
    at com.neberox.app.libraries.mega.megaJNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
```

What should i do to make AndroidStudio read these files.

Comment: Please share your build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During compilation, the native libraries are packaged only if there path has been specified in the `build.gradle` file.

Check this:

```
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs'
}
```

As an example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cprakashagr.jni"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23

        ndk {
            moduleName "ndkfoo"
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' //set libs as .so's location instead of jni
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call with auto-generated Android.mk file
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

Reference: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Comment: in which build gradle and where to place this

Comment: also it gives me error Gradle DSL method not found main()

Comment: You have to specify it in the module level `build.gradle` file. I have edited my post for an example.

Comment: Could you confirm you have the latest gradle distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties? Please cross check once: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip`

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to @cprakashagr 's post, you could try using ReLinker or Facebook's SoLoader library to ensure that the system finds your native library.

https://github.com/KeepSafe/ReLinker

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this answer. Its seems a very good alternative.

Comment: Well you will also need to do what you said, it's just that this fixes additional errors in loading the library.